# Knockout Custom Binder applies after ko.applyBindings

Tags: knockout.js

**Question**: How do I get the binder to apply it's bindings since the binder executes after the ApplyBindings() function?

I've tried ordering them differently, same file, different files, etc. Nothing seems to work, I try re-apply bindings and it yells at me about multiple-bindings per context.

**My View**

```
@* Page Content *@
<h1><span class="entity-type" data-bind="text: $data[0].EntityType"></span></h1>
<a data-bind="attr: { href: '/Entity/Create?EntityType=' + $data[0].EntityType() }" class="ignore">New</a>
<form>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr data-bind="template: { name: 'HeaderRowTemplate', foreach: $data[0].Properties }">
                <td data-bind="text: Name, visible: SummaryProperty"></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'DataRowTemplate', foreach: $data }">

        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>

@section Scripts {  
    @* Templates *@
    <script id="HeaderRowTemplate" type="text/html">
        <td data-bind="text: Name, visible: SummaryProperty"></td>
    </script>

    <script id="DataRowTemplate" type="text/html">
        <tr data-bind="template: { name: 'DataItemTemplate', foreach: Properties }"></tr>
    </script>

    <script id="DataItemTemplate" type="text/html">
        <td data-bind="visible: SummaryProperty">
            <input data-bind="editorFor: Value.ValueAsString" />
        </td>
    </script>
}
```

**My MVC Model Serializing:**

```
@* Scripts *@
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ApplyBindings() {
        var data = @Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model)),
            viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    }
    ApplyBindings();
</script>
```

**My Custom Binder:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.editorFor = { // Note: Binder is a Work-In-Progress.
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var val = valueAccessor(),
            dataType = bindingContext.$data.DataType,
            innerBindingContext = bindingContext.extend(valueAccessor);

        if (dataType() == 'unit') {
            // Bind to a input & dropdown.
            element.outerHTML += "<select data-bind='options: Value.Value.AllowedUnits'></select>";
            ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(innerBindingContext, element);
        } else if (dataType() == 'dropdown') {
            // Bind to a dropdown.
            element.outerHTML = "<select data-bind=\"options: Value.Value.DropDown.Options, optionsText: 'Name', optionsCaption: 'Desciption', value: $data.Value.Value.DropDown.Selected \"></select>";
        } else if (dataType() == 'entity') {
            // TODO: Add logic for entities later.

        } else {
            element.outerHTML = "<input data-bind=\"value: Value.ValueAsString\" />"; // Current Issue Area.
        }

        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(innerBindingContext, element);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContex) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leveraging knockout's templating engine is going to be your best bet.

```
return ko.bindingHandlers.template.init(element, options, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)
```

from within your other binding handler, while passing on the parameters you received from the original binding handler. You obviously can take liberties with your options, just be sure the options object contains the 'name' property:

```
{ name: 'name-of-template', data: { foo1: 0, foo2: false } }
```

At this point, you shouldn't have to applyBindingsToAnything.

Comment: I'm not certain I quite understand? I currently am using templates, however, I had to add the custom binder to handle my dynamic values. What is the return statement supposed to be accomplishing?

Comment: The point would be to use another template instead of 'adding HTML' through jQuery. If you process this through knockout's template binding you will automatically have your bindings working for you.